# Owl Carousel navigation arrows not working on WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, navigation, owl-carousel

Navigation arrows are not working - they are unclickable. This is based in WordPress - we are not using a plugin because this is a custom job. See it here at the bottom of the white section about halfway down the page:

http://foster.gw.sandbox.uconnectlabs.com/

What I'd be overjoyed to see happen is having posts scroll from one to another when a user clicks on the navigation arrows.

Some things to note:

- The carousel will be scrolling through posts in WordPress rather than images.
- In order to target these posts for "carouseling", I put a wrapper around the posts section named "posting-wrapper".
- The ".post" class is what gets targeted as an item to be scrolled.
- It looks like all of the HTML below is generated by the jQuery code beneath it. I have not manually entered any of the Owl Carousel HTML - it is generated automatically, apparently by Owl Carousel itself. Perhaps the .owl-carousel() method does this, but I'm not certain.
- The only thing wrong is the absence of linking/scrolling on the arrow characters.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="posting-wrapper owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">
    <div class="owl-stage-outer">
    <div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 1220px;">
        <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 406.667px; margin-right: 0px;">
        <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 406.667px; margin-right: 0px;">
        <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 406.667px; margin-right: 0px;">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-controls">
    <div class="owl-nav">
        <div class="icon-angle-left nav-prev" style=""></div>
        <div class="icon-angle-right nav-next" style=""></div>
    </div>
<div class="owl-dots" style="">
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
if (jQuery(".posting-wrapper .post").length > 2){ // If it detects more than two entities, do the following...
jQuery(".posting-wrapper").addClass('owl-carousel');
jQuery(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    nav: true,
    navText: ['', ''],
    navClass: [ 'icon-angle-left nav-prev', 'icon-angle-right nav-next' ]
})
}
```

I noticed in the jQuery code that the properties are set to "nav" and "navText", etc, which look like abbreviated versions of what Owl Carousel uses - navigation, navigationText, respectively. When I change these properties to the unabbreviated versions, strange things happen (like the nav doesn't appear... go figure).

I think the person who set it up may have used their own classes, etc, but... yeah. Don't know how it affects the navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when there are more than 3 posts, they should scroll? I can only see 3 posts in your wrapper .owl-stage. Should there be more in there? Maybe in your PHP your limiting yourself to 3 posts?

Comment: Nice call - it was actually a line in PHP that was fetching the posts: $custom_main_loop = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) ); I increased it to 5 and put "item: 3" in the Owl Carousel jQuery and that fixed it! Hooray! (Thanks a lot!)